Changing values over a certain number in a pandas dataframe
I am working with some data to predict whether or not someone will have a stroke. My dataset contains several rows I have converted to binary values, but I am struggling to fix my age variable. If someone is 65 or older it, should be a 1, if not it should be 0.
I tried a few methods, but each one gave me the same error, that a equal to or less than sign is not supported between 'str' and 'int'. I tried a replace method but it gave me the same error. How can I change these values in my dataframe?

The error you mentioned "equal to or less than sign is not supported between 'str' and 'int'" indicates that your age column is likely a combination of string and integer. We can try to convert into a number first.Here is a sample  example :
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'age': ['67', '32', '75', '45', '65']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert age to numeric
# The errors='coerce' argument will convert non-numeric values to NaN. You 
# can handle these missing values later using techniques like imputation 
#  or dropping rows.
df['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['age'], errors='coerce')

# Create binary age column
df['is_elderly'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 65 else 0)

print(df)


if you have column age in your data, to create such binary you can use:
df['above_65'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['age'], errors='coerce') > 65).astype(int)
